# How to make facebook canvas shrink?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I have set canvas to have fluid size, but after resizing window of browser, size of iframe doesn't change. It stays permanently at 760px.

I need it becouse my client wants to have resposive front-end in fb application, but I'm not sure if it is possible anyway.

The question is: how to make it works?

Comment: `FB.setAutoGrow` does only expand the canvas height – if you want it to shrink, you have to call `FB.setSize` instead with the desired target height.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrink size of facebook canvas app](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14525917/shrink-size-of-facebook-canvas-app)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I guess you're talking about horizontal resizing - this should definitely happening (even without calling FB.setAutoGrow) as soon as you activate the according option:

[image]

In fact this works even if you don't load the JS-SDK at all.

Here's a demo: https://apps.facebook.com/lastfm-og-scrobbler/

Comment: And your demo doesn't shrink. Canvas has the same size all the time